# Integrity error while adding item to database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

So I am trying to add an item to my database inside my django app. However, I keep getting an integrity error while trying to do so.
The error looks like this:

```
IntegrityError at /newcategory
NOT NULL constraint failed: buyit_category.tag
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/newcategory
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: buyit_category.tag
```

I had the field "tag" for my category but did remove it, since I didn't really need it. I also made migrations and migrated the altered model, so I am quite confused on why it keeps giving me that error.

Here is my view for that part:

```
@require_POST
def newCategory(request):
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_category = Category(name=request.POST['name'])
        new_category.save()

    return redirect('items')
```

this is the template which is getting rendered:

```
{% extends 'buyit/base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<h4>NEUE KATEGORIE HINZUFÜGEN</h4>

<form action="{% url 'newCategory' %}" method="POST" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            {{ form.name }}
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="add-btn">Hinzufügen</button>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the model I am using:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I also tried to add the tag field back and set null to true but that didn't solve my error either.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you run your migrations and restarted the application service? check with the database to see if that tag attribute still exists at the database level.

Comment: The migration was marked as applied by mistake? Try faking to a previous migration `migrate --fake <your_app> <previous_migration>` and then migrating again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define items first:

```
def items(request):
    return render(request, '/items')

def newCategory(request):
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_category = Category(name=request.POST['name'])
        new_category.save()

    return redirect(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if your form is a modelform or not, but if it is I'd suggest trying to save the form instead of calling on posted data. If you do need to reference the data supplied from the broswer, use 'cleaned_data' (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) instead of request.POST. In your case that line would become:

`new_category = Category(name=form.cleaned_data['name'])`

But I think you just want to save the form, and let it handle the creation of category.

```
def newCategory(request):
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return redirect('items')
```